# How do I change the text spacing in legends created using plstream::stripc

Tags: c++, plplot

I'm generating strip charts using plplot in c++, but the spacing between the legend entries is such that the characters overlap making them difficult to read. Does anyone know how to set the test spacing for legends generated using plstream::stripc? Thanks